# Sort a mongodb query by Int32 field

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a Mongodb query that is being used in pagination.
The pagination works so long as I don't use any sorting or orderby.

Can anyone tell me what is the problem with this query?
**votes** is an Int32 column.

```
x = [person for person in mongo.db.users.find({'user': name}).sort("votes", -1)]
```

Comment: What is the problem, what happens when you do as you said? If you get error please provide the full error output.

Comment: There is no error.
It's part of a pagination function. But the query doesn't return results ordered by votes and drops some docs completely

Comment: Could you post sample collection where query fails

Answer (score 0):

Your error in `sort`:

```
mongo.db.find({'user': name}).sort({'votes':-1})
```

reference Link : [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/)

Answer (score -1):

You can use skip() & limit() here

Comment: This is not an answer, it should be a comment